# Apache2 Virtual Host fails with Name or service not known

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Moving from Ubuntu 17.10 to Mint 18.3 and migrating virtual host config files fails with

```
[core:error] [pid 3012] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name
```

On my fresh installed Mint i have done this first
1)  sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

This is my standard Config File using for Vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *.domain.localhost:80>
    ServerName domain.localhost
    ServerAlias www.domain.localhost api.domain.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/dev/projects/domain/web/html/
    <Directory /home/dev/projects/domain/web/html/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW: This steps i'm doing for every project
1) sudo chown -R www-data:www-data PATH_TO_DIR
2) sudo chmod 660 -R PATH_TO_DIR
3) sudo chmod -R -x+X PATH_TO_DIR
4) sudo find PATH_TO_DIR -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
5) sudo setfacl -R -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::- PATH_TO_DIR

UPDATE:
adding domains to /etc/hosts, reloading server leads again to the default

Comment: is `domain.localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @ivanivan  No it is not. I never had to add Virtual Host Domains to hosts

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by modifying "000-default.conf" DocumentRoot Path, then modifying "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" by adding these lines

```
<Directory /home/mdev/_projects/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also this had to be changed from

```
<VirtualHost *.domain.localhost:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

No entries at /etc/hosts neccassary!